# Extract WHY label was chosen on classification?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I currently have a system set up where I train from old posts/categories and try to predict what category a new post will be. I am using a pipeline with `TfidfVectorizer` and `LinearSVC` to train the dataset and storing that in a pickle, then I process new posts by loading that pickle and using `predict` from the loaded pickle to classify the new posts. Currently, I am struggling with a few labels and I don't know why.

I am looking to provide some output on what words were triggered in the new post for each classification label so that I can see why a certain label was chosen when classifying new data against a training set, but I cannot find a way to do this.

I know that I can output the top features in my vectorizer when I am training, but how can I output essentially the *reason* why a certain label was chosen over another one?

Comment: That's typically something that cannot be done for any machine learning model, generally also not for support vector machines. It might be more useful to use a decision tree classifier instead for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the training phase of the SVM for each word of the corpus vocabulary you learn a weight for each of the classes.

Then, during inference, you calculate the dot product between the class weights and the vector description of the instance to be classified. The algorithm returns the class that yields the highest dot product scores. Hence, you can have an estimate of how things work by examining those weights (`coef_` attribute) for your instance.

I agree however that other methods like trees are more interpretable.